# Appointment in calendars use wrong time from ics file

Tags: icalendar

I am generating a .ics file. When I import it to a calendar app (such as the on on OSX or iOS) it says:

20:00 to 21:00

18:00 to 19:00 (GMT)

But I need to have the time of the appointment to be 18:00 to 19:00 by default (GMT time). How can I do it?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:xxx
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Zurich
X-WR-CALDESC:
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Zurich
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Zurich
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Event:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20140929T180000Z
DTEND:20140929T190000Z
DTSTAMP:20141001T223333Z
UID:542c651df4095
DESCRIPTION:Keine
SUMMARY:Mindblowers
LOCATION:
URL;VALUE=URI:xxx
END:VEVENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most calendar applications will display in the timezone that you have set in the app.  So to see times in GMT time, set the timezone of the app to GMT.

Alternatively you may not really be meaning that you want 18:00 to 19:00 (GMT) but that you want 18:00 to 19:00 no matter what timezone the app is in.  This is called a 'floating time' (like an alarm that wakes you at 7am no matter what city or timezone you are in, no at 7am back home).
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-32

> For example, the following represents January 18, 1998, at
> 11 PM:
>
> ```
>    19980118T230000
>
>   DATE-TIME values of this type are said to be "floating" and are
>   not bound to any time zone in particular.  They are used to
>   represent the same hour, minute, and second value regardless of
>   which time zone is currently being observed.
> ```

Comment: Thank you! removing the Z in the timestamp worked :)